# How to Install SSL Certificate in ubuntu (apache2)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, apache2

i've buy a SSL-Certification for my domain,

they sended for me 4 files

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
 mydomaine.crt
```

I've tried many ways to install it but every tutorial ask for the private key that i don't have

can anyone guide me to do it?

Comment: A certificate is useless without the corresponding private key.

Comment: So i need to ask for the key?

Comment: Usually you a) upload the key during the process of creating the cert. b) the key is generated during the process and you get it on the screen to store away.

If the providers security is bad you can download the private key or ask for it but it should have been removed. But they should be able to give you a new key for free if you explain the situation.

Or if you want a free option you just go for https://letsencrypt.org/
I think this link should get you started.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04
Good Luck